# Excel - Unfilitering and Data Changes

Tags: excel, filtering, excel-2007

I am working on consolidating data in an excel spreadsheet. (I wish I could use another tool but excel is what we use at work)

Since there are many different spreadsheets and some have information regarding the same line item I colored the ID number to know which line item came from which spreadsheet of data. Then I filtered based on color and input some data. When I unfiltered the data it changed the cells and of data in the column that I edited. My guess is that when I'm unfiltering the rows of data that I changed are staying in their current cells and the rows are moving and therefore attributing the data I input to different line items than I had originally populated.

Ive tried multiple times to fix the issue and have done some research but I can't seem to make sure the data stays in the correct line.

Is there an excel option or way I could fix this? Does it have to do with the filtering on color? When I filter based on value this does not occur but it would be easier to keep it filtered on color. 
Thanks.

Here is an example of what happens (not the actually spreadsheet of data):
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I am running Excel on a VDI and I know that applications tend to be buggy on virtual desktops. Is there a way in excel to fix the bug?

Comment: I would recommend adding a column to the data with a field "data source" rather than relying on color. Even Excel isn't so buggy that it would overwrite the data ( I hope... )

Comment: I tried that and ran into the same problem. So I guess its not the filtering by color thats causing the issue. Good thought though.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you are seeing? I can't reproduce the problem from your description thus far.

Comment: I created a screenshot example of what happens, not sure how to add it here. Can I send it to you somehow or do you know of a way to attach screen shots?

Comment: Post the image on imgur with a link - I can then edit the post to make it appear right in the question. Afraid I'm about to get in a car... will look later tonight.

Comment: yes the range is a colored-filtered range of data but it was still causing issues when I did not filter on color. I also cannot post the actual document from work. So I just created an example of what was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When filtered excel simply hides the other rows and shows the filtered data. When copying to other cells, if there are other cells in between the copied cells the format and copy goes to those cells as well. The way around this is to copy and past directly, one by one, to the cells you want (if there are hidden cells in between, else you can copy all the way down). It is tedious but solves the issue.